# Can you control the PDF description that shows in browser tabs?

Tags: beamer, pdf, titles, viewers

I've taken to using browsers as my go-to PDF viewer over the last few years and I've noticed that most TeX documents have an issue with the title as it appears in the browser. The title seems to be automatically determined based on the first text that appears after `\begin{document}`

I've tried setting optional arguments to `\title`, comments, etc. I've looked for an answer online but haven't found one.

Is there an intended way to explicitly set this value?

Below is a MWE, note that this isn't specific to beamer-type documents.

- I've generated the file as `test.pdf`.
- The browser tab description is: `*1.5cm My Presentation [width=0.6\textheight] My Name My University August 23, 2013 - test.pdf`
- The `*1.5cm` appear due `\vspace*{1.5cm}`

Code:

```
\documentclass[9pt,mathserif,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\\
    \textsc{\LARGE My Presentation}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textheight]{example-image}\\
    \large My Name\\
    \large My University\\
    \large \today
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is what shows up on Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Here is what shows up on Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

---

Edit: Removed unnecessary `\centering` from above.

Additional information:

- Compiled using TeXMaker 5.1.3, calling TeXLive 2022
- Windows 10, Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045
- To open PDF: Right-click `->` open with `->` Chrome / Firefox

Comment: You will usually see the document title there (sometimes suffixed by the filename), which seems to include some formatting stuff do to your image inclusion. I would recommend to manually overwrite these PDF properties for this reason, for example using `\hypersetup{pdftitle={Your PDF title},}` after including the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh I tried this and it unfortunately didn't work. I think your suggestion is definitely in line with the solution I'm trying to find though.

Comment: @Kvo, so I'd put Win10 on the suspect list for now ... I'm not there yet, for reasons ... and you seem to do more or less what I did. So the OS may be the relevant difference. // Can you compile your test.tex on a different computer, not running under Win10? // BTW: do the property windows on your system match my screenshots below?

Comment: Wrt @epR8GaYuh s remark to my answer, all you want to do is change the content of the browsers TAB ?

Comment: My properties match yours. I do have Ubuntu on my other partition but unfortunately, I'm running some jobs at the moment and can't restart.  That being said, I've noticed this same issue on most other PDFs sent to me over the years.  -- Yes, I do just want to change what is displayed in the browser's TAB.

Comment: Use the pdfdisplaydoctitle option, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49143/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added `\usepackage{hyperref}    \hypersetup{pdftitle=TestTitle,pdfdisplaydoctitle}` to my preamble (and a few other places in the document as well) but unfortunately this didn't work either.

Comment: I can check later what beamer is doing

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `usepdftitle=false` option to prevent beamer to use the argument of `\title` as pdftitle. Then you can set your own title with `pdftitle` and force it into the top with `pdfdisplaydoctitle`:

```
\documentclass[9pt,mathserif,aspectratio=169,usepdftitle=false]{beamer}

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\\
    \textsc{\LARGE My Presentation}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textheight]{example-image}\\
    \large My Name\\
    \large My University\\
    \large \today
}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=blub,pdfdisplaydoctitle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of messing with the content of the title macro, you could use the appropriate fields (`\author`, `\institute`, etc.) for your information. Then beamer can pick up the correct title for the pdf meta data.

The main difference between the default beamer title page and your hacked version is the graphic below the title. With a current beamer v3.70, you could simply add it to the `title` template. As a bonus point, this will give you correct line spacing.

```
\documentclass[9pt,mathserif,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}

\title{My Presentation}
\author{My Name}
\institute{My University}

\addtobeamertemplate{title}{}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textheight]{example-image}}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE,series=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet an other way to do it:
define your own template.

- beamer prepared many templates and predefined macros for this purpose
- my answer combines a solution proposed by [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25318/245790) and (most of) your data
- for the graphics beamer provides at least a logo
- please check [the manual](https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more details
- for more inspiration kindly check for [defbeamertemplate here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=defbeamertemplate)

FireFox:

[image: result]

Document properties:

[image: docProp]

Code:

```
% Adapted from this solution: 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25318/245790

\documentclass[9pt,mathserif,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}

% ~~~ you need to define your own template "what to place where" ~~~~~
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
 \begin{center}
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic   
 \end{center}

}

% ~~~ here you set the content of aboves variables ~~~~
\title{My Presentation}
\subtitle{related to whatever}
\author{My Name}
\institute{My University}
\date{\today}

% ~~~ there you go ~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, how you compile your document, which operating system you're using or how you call `test.pdf` to open in your browser (please add this information to your **question**, not to comments).

#### 1. Analysis

However, with these modifications it compiles using Texmaker (Editor, calling MikTex installation) as `beamerFileName.pdf` from `beamerFileName.tex`:

- `\usepackage{graphicx}`
- delete or comment out `%    \centering` (you can't center, what's already centered horizontally)

However, as a non-user of class beamer I'm not sure, if your call of the first frame is ok: I suspect, not.

FireFox: `beamerFileName.pdf`

[image: ff]

Explorer:

[image: explorer]

```
\documentclass[9pt,mathserif,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{
%    \centering
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\\
    \textsc{\LARGE My Presentation}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textheight]{example-image}\\
    \large My Name\\
    \large My University\\
    \large \today
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### 2. Properties

However, if I check the files properties in the (file) explorer, the field title holds most of the strange "file name" you report:

[image: propExpl]

Similar for the documents properties, you can access via the browser, Acrobat etc.:

[image: docProp]

For other documentclasses I'd set these fields via `\usepackage{hyperref}`, see its manual at `ctan.org`.

#### 3. Conclusion

For some strange reason your computer seems to rebuild the filename using `field title` AND `test.pdf` into a kind of URL.

Mine doesen't, neither be double-clicking on `beamerFileName.pdf`, nor by envoking Acrobat via Texmakers icon.

Comment: About (3): There is nothing strange about the PDF viewer suffixing the actual PDF metadata title with the actual filename as the website title. For Firefox, this is just how it is implemented in the PDF viewer (pdf.js). Some standalone PDF viewers like Evince do something similar to quickly see which document you actually opened as well.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. I edited my question but I'll post the requested info here too. 

Compiled TeXMaker 5.1.3//TeXLive 2022 on Windows 10, Version 10.0.19045. To open the PDF it doesn't matter which way (via the viewer button on TeXMaker, setting default PDF viewer, or the 'open with' in the right-click menu.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh, true: looks like I interpreted the tabs in the screenshots  as the URL displayed. (Mine does the same, see my screenshots.)

Comment: You don't need to add `\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer will automatically load it.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, good to know.

Comment: @MS-SPO btw: what do you think is wrong with the first frame? It looks completely fine.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, uncommening the mentioned part resulted in unwanted non-scaling, shifts etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with `non-scaling`, but `\titlepage` should be within a frame. Otherwise beamer can't set up the correct frame geometry.

Comment: Sorry, puzzled with a different question. Leaving \centering gave a compile error, so I removed it.